# javascript calculation when user did not entered few rows (add remaining row values)

Tags: javascript, html

Here i posted my javascript and html coding. If user clicks the calculate total button it should add all values and shown in the textbox. That works perfectly. But problem is if user entered (totally 7 rows here ftotal,ftotal1,ftotal2,ftotal3,ftotal4,ftotal5,ftotal6) 5 rows values and when they click the calculate total button the text field shown NaN. I want if they didn't entered few rows remaining rows will be caluculated and shown in text box when they click the button....???

**JavaScript**

```
function calfinal(frm) {
    var ftotal = frm.ftotal.value
    var ftotal1 = frm.ftotal1.value
    var ftotal2 = frm.ftotal2.value
    var ftotal3 = frm.ftotal3.value
    var ftotal4 = frm.ftotal4.value
    var ftotal5 = frm.ftotal5.value
    var ftotal6 = frm.ftotal6.value
    var calc = 0
        ftotal = parseFloat(ftotal)
        ftotal1 = parseFloat(ftotal1)
        ftotal2 = parseFloat(ftotal2)
        ftotal3 = parseFloat(ftotal3)
        ftotal4 = parseFloat(ftotal4)
        ftotal5 = parseFloat(ftotal5)
        ftotal6 = parseFloat(ftotal6)
        answer = ftotal + ftotal1 + ftotal2 + ftotal3 + ftotal4 + ftotal5 + ftotal6
        frm.calc.value = answer
}
```

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td height="30" class="tabform"><input type="text" size="10" name="ftotal" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="30" class="tabform"><input type="text" size="10" name="ftotal1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="30" class="tabform"><input type="text" size="10" name="ftotal2"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="30" class="tabform"><input type="text" size="10" name="ftotal3"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="30" class="tabform"><input type="text" size="10" name="ftotal4"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="30" class="tabform"><input type="text" size="10" name="ftotal5"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="30" class="tabform"><input type="text" size="10" name="ftotal6"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="15"><input type="button" value="Calculate Total" onClick="calfinal(this.form);" /></td>
    <td height="15" align="center"><input type="text" size="10" name="calc" readonly="readonly" /></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function [isNaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) to verify for each value is a number.

If it is not you just don't include it in your calculation or you set it to 0;

so something like this:

```
function calfinal(frm) {
    var ftotal = frm.ftotal.value
    var ftotal1 = frm.ftotal1.value
    var ftotal2 = frm.ftotal2.value
    var ftotal3 = frm.ftotal3.value
    var ftotal4 = frm.ftotal4.value
    var ftotal5 = frm.ftotal5.value
    var ftotal6 = frm.ftotal6.value
    var calc = 0
    ftotal = (!isNaN(ftotal) && ftotal!="") ? parseFloat(ftotal) : 0
    ftotal1 = (!isNaN(ftotal1) && ftotal1!="") ? parseFloat(ftotal1) : 0
    ftotal2 = (!isNaN(ftotal2) && ftotal2!="") ? parseFloat(ftotal2) : 0
    ftotal3 = (!isNaN(ftotal3) && ftotal3!="") ? parseFloat(ftotal3) : 0
    ftotal4 = (!isNaN(ftotal4) && ftotal4!="") ? parseFloat(ftotal4) : 0
    ftotal5 = (!isNaN(ftotal5) && ftotal5!="") ? parseFloat(ftotal5) : 0    
    ftotal6 = (!isNaN(ftotal6) && ftotal6!="") ? parseFloat(ftotal6) : 0

    if(!isNaN(ftotal6))
    {
        console.log(ftotal6)        
    }
    answer = ftotal + ftotal1 + ftotal2 + ftotal3 + ftotal4 + ftotal5 + ftotal6
    frm.calc.value = answer
}
```

Here a example of it working http://jsfiddle.net/CdsBW/

**edit** maybe short this to a function:

```
function validateNumber(number)
{
    return (!isNaN(number) && number!="") ? parseFloat(number) : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see how user can enter any values as the input fields are all readonly.  Anyway, why do you not initialize the values to 0.0 or write your own function which checks the value before calling parseFloat?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this , Users must enter value before addition, if incase you can also provide default values [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QMKje/)

```
function calfinal(frm)
{
   var ele =frm.getElementsByTagName('input');
   for(var i=0;i<ele.length-1;i++) // -1 is for excluding last input element used to diplay result
   {
     if(ele[i].value == "" && ele[i].getAttribute('type')=='text')
     {
         alert("required field");
         ele[i].focus();
         return;
     }
   }

   // below this write your code for addition
}
```

If you want to add only value provided boxes then you can try

```
function calfinal(frm)
{
   var ele =frm.getElementsByTagName('input');
   var sum=0;
   for(var i=0;i<ele.length-1;i++)
   {
     if(ele[i].value != "" && ele[i].getAttribute('type')=='text')
     {
         sum += parseFloat(ele[i].value);
     }

   }

   // sum will contain the result
}
```

Comment: this code little bit worked. but problem is result values are showing like concatenation. for example if i entered 50 and 50 . answer is 100 . but it shown 50 + 50..

Comment: function calfinal(frm)
{
   var ele =frm.getElementsByTagName('input');
   var sum=0;
   for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
   {
     if(ele[i].value != "" && ele[i].getAttribute('type')=='text')
     {
         sum += parseFloat(ele[i].value);
     }

   }
 var ftotal = frm.ftotal.value
 var ftotal1 = frm.ftotal1.value
 var ftotal2 = frm.ftotal2.value
 var ftotal3 = frm.ftotal3.value
 var ftotal4 = frm.ftotal4.value
 var ftotal5 = frm.ftotal5.value
 var ftotal6 = frm.ftotal6.value
 answer = ftotal + ftotal1 + ftotal2 + ftotal3 + ftotal4 + ftotal5 + ftotal6
 frm.calc.value = answer

}